# 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I get the error while trying to compile a WPF Project with Visual Studio 2013.

Error   3   Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

I have VS 2013/2015 and 2019 all the three installed on the same machine.
Is this causing a conflict or mandating me to add reference to System.Windows - 5.0.5.

I do not see this error on machines with only VS 2013. How could it be possibly related or is there something else which I am missing?

Please note - The project is compiled against .NET Framework 4.0 and the System.Windows.dll which I have referred is also of version 4.0.0.0

Thanks in advance.
Sandeep

Comment: These problems i faced are mostly due to target .Net Framework. What you can do is remove reference to Windows.dll and refer it again with nuget package manager/Console which will refer it with target framwork.

Comment: here's some tips: add all wpf references such as windowsbase and presentationcore, restart VS, clean your solution, delete bin and obj folders, check your csproj file, make sure reference version is ok (or remove the version) and that assembly is not referenced by its path. I would suggest converting to project sdk format to avoid headaches in the future